# A parse function for text line with fields separated by a comma with the known number and their type

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to parse a line with a fixed amount of fields and known types.

```
using Text = FieldType<std::string>;
using Int = FieldType<int>;

using Name = Text;
using TextSpecificField = Text;
using IntSpecificField = Int;

struct LineData
{
    Name name;
    TextSpecificField textField;
    IntSpecificField intField;
    // LineData contains 12 fields in total, types are known
};

struct InvalidLine { std::string line, err; };

using Line = std::variant<LineData, InvalidLine>;
```

With that, I can write a parsing function for each specific field type:

```
template<Field T>
constexpr auto parse(std::string_view field) -> detail::ReturnOptErr<T>
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Text, T>)
    {
        return {decltype(T::value){field}};
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Int, T>)
    {
        auto [value, err] = toNum<decltype(T::value)>(field); // Why typename T::value doesn't work?
        return {T{value}, std::move(err)};
    }
    else
    {
        []<bool flag = false> { static_assert(flag, "no match"); }();
    }
}
```

Here my problem starts with the below parse function. I am having trouble wrapping my head around trying to simplify this piece of code. As it can be seen, there is a repeating pattern that I would like to abstract:

```
auto parse(std::string_view line) -> Line
{
    // Parsing a string and returning string is done intentionally to show repeating pattern
    auto [nameStr, rest] = split(line, ',');
    auto name = parse<Name>(nameStr);
    if (name.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(name.errorText.value())};
    }

    auto [textStr, rest2] = split(rest, ',');
    auto textField = parse<TextSpecificField>(textStr);
    if (textField.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(textField.errorText.value())};
    }

    auto [intStr, rest3] = split(rest2, ',');
    auto intField = parse<IntSpecificField>(intStr);
    if (intField.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(intField.errorText.value())};
    }

    return LineData{std::move(name.value), std::move(textField.value), intField.value};
}
```

Is there an elegant way to approach this? I thought about using exceptions, but I don't like that solution. I also tried to approach this problem using [template recursion](https://godbolt.org/z/aaTWc8sMd), but I could not come up with an idea of returning `Line` from such a parser.

[Full example](https://godbolt.org/z/1b4rxr5Kh)

BR

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

// - Utility ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace detail
{
template <typename FieldType>
struct ReturnOptErr
{
    FieldType value;
    std::optional<std::string> errorText;
};
} // namespace detail

template<typename T>
constexpr auto toNum(std::string_view valueStr) -> detail::ReturnOptErr<T>
{
    // Implementation of number parsing using <charconv>
    return detail::ReturnOptErr<T>{123};
}

constexpr auto split(std::string_view input, char delim) noexcept -> std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>
{
    auto const delimPos = input.find(delim);
    if (delimPos == std::string_view::npos)
    {
        return {input, ""};
    }

    auto const token = input.substr(0, delimPos);
    auto const rest = input.substr(delimPos + 1);
    return {token, rest};
}

// - Data ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T>
struct FieldType
{
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
concept Field = std::is_same_v<FieldType<decltype(T::value)>, T>;

auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, Field auto const& field) -> std::ostream&
{
    return os << field.value;
}

using Text = FieldType<std::string>;
using Int = FieldType<int>;

using Name = Text;
using TextSpecificField = Text;
using IntSpecificField = Int;
// more field types

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct LineData
{
    Name name;
    TextSpecificField textField;
    IntSpecificField intField;
    // LineData containts 12 fields in total, types are known
};

struct InvalidLine { std::string line, err; };

using Line = std::variant<LineData, InvalidLine>;

// - Parser ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<Field T>
constexpr auto parse(std::string_view field) -> detail::ReturnOptErr<T>
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Text, T>)
    {
        return {decltype(T::value){field}};
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Int, T>)
    {
        auto [value, err] = toNum<decltype(T::value)>(field); // Why typename T::value doesn't work?
        return {T{value}, std::move(err)};
    }
    else
    {
        []<bool flag = false> { static_assert(flag, "no match"); }();
    }
}



auto parse(std::string_view line) -> Line
{
    // Parsing a string and returning string is done intentionally to show repeating pattern
    auto [nameStr, rest] = split(line, ',');
    auto name = parse<Name>(nameStr);
    if (name.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(name.errorText.value())};
    }

    auto [textStr, rest2] = split(rest, ',');
    auto textField = parse<TextSpecificField>(textStr);
    if (textField.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(textField.errorText.value())};
    }

    auto [intStr, rest3] = split(rest2, ',');
    auto intField = parse<IntSpecificField>(intStr);
    if (intField.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(intField.errorText.value())};
    }

    return LineData{std::move(name.value), std::move(textField.value), intField.value};
}



int main()
{
    std::string lineStr = "name, text, 123456";
    auto lineVar = parse(lineStr);
    auto& line = std::get<LineData>(lineVar);

    std::cout << line.name << ", " << line.textField << ", " << line.intField << "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to take a look at how this sort of thing is handled by the combination of boos::fusion and boost::qi. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you, that is interesting concept to write a parser, probably even high quality one, but I would like to stick to a hand-written one. I am satisfied with what I got after I applied G. Sliepen suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Create a helper function

To reduce the code repetition, a classic solution is to write a helper function. You can do that here as well. First let's look at how we want `parse()` to look:

```
auto parse(std::string_view line) -> Line
{
    LineData data;
    parse_field(line, &data.name);
    parse_field(line, &data.textField);
    parse_field(line, &data.intField);
    return data;
}
```

The function `parse_field()` gets a reference to the member of `data`, and by making it a template it can deduce the type for us. It could look like:

```
void parse_field(std::string_view& line, auto& member)
{
    auto [field, line] = split(line, ',');
    member = parse<decltype(member)>(field);
}
```

Note the *reference* to `line` in the latter function. I have also omitted all the error checking here, that should be added back of course. Note that you can do that in a way that still preserves the simple structure of `parse()` above. For example, you could pass a reference to a `InvalidLine` to `parse_field()`, and have `parse_field()` return a `bool` on error, so you can chain the calls to `parse_field()` with `||`.

You still need to repeat `parse_field(line, &data.member)` for each member, you can reduce even that by creating a variadic `parse_fields()` function, so that in `parse()` you only have to write:

```
auto parse(std::string_view line) -> Line
{
    LineData data;
    parse_fields(line, &data.name, &data.textField, &data.intField);
    return data;
}
```

## A fully generic solution

It would be nice to create a fully generic `parse()` function that would work with any `struct`, not just `Line`. It is unfortunate that C++ doesn't have introspection yet; because ideally you would write a function like:

```
template<typename LineType>
requires std::is_class<LineType>
auto parse(std::string_view line) {
    LineType result;
    for (member: LineType) {
        auto [field, line] = split(line, ',');
        result.member = parse<decltype(result.member)>(field);
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, you can approach this hypothetical solution by using a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) instead of a `struct` to hold all the fields of a line. A solution could then look like so:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_tuple = false;
template<typename ... Ts>
constexpr bool is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> = true;

template<TupleType>
requires is_tuple<TupleType>
auto parse(std::string_view line) {
    TupleType result;

    auto parse_one = [&](auto& arg) {
        auto [field, line] = split(line, ',');
        arg = parse<decltype(arg)>(field);
    };
         
    std::apply([&](auto&... args) {
        (parse_one(args), ...);
    }, result);

    return result;
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
using LineData = std::tuple<Name, textField, intField>;
...
LineData data = parse<decltype(data)>(line);
```

You can avoid having to pass the type as a template parameter by not using a return value but passing the result using a reference function parameter. Of course the drawback is that getting access to the fields in a tuple is not very nice.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Regarding the first part of the answer "helper function": When error checking is added back, we are back with repeated ifs, basically only split will be abstracted. Also in `parse_field`, the `line` is reassigned, too bad there is no way to make it work with structured bindings. As for the second part of the answer "generic solution": It is nice a solution. This one actually addresses the problem, but I would like to stick with the struct for my data model.

Comment: It's still doable without falling back to repeated `if`s. I've added a hint at a possible solution to the answer.

Comment: I see now, thank you. I'm going to accept this answer. However, I am still not satisfied with the general approach using in-out parameters.

Comment: You could use a lambda function that captures `[&]` to avoid the in-out parameters, but under the hood it's all the same. Also, if someone comes up with a better idea, you can always change the accepted answer.