# A parse function for text line with fields separated by a comma with the known number and their type, simplified version

Tags: c++, c++20, variant-type

simplifying this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278647/a-parse-function-for-text-line-with-fields-separated-by-a-comma-with-the-known-n), taking most of the comment into considerations, I ended up with this version, looking for some feedback

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

std::tuple<std::string_view, std::string_view> split(std::string_view str, char delimiter)
{
    auto pos = str.find(delimiter);
    if (pos == std::string_view::npos)
    {
        return {str, {}};
    }
    return {str.substr(0, pos), str.substr(pos + 1)};
}
template <typename T>
auto parse(std::string_view str)
{
    using T2 = std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>;
    T2 res;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T2, std::string>) { return res =  std::string(str);}
    if (std::is_floating_point_v<T2>){ return res =  std::stod(std::string(str));return res;}
    if (std::is_integral_v<T2>)  { return res = std::stol(std::string(str));}
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid type");
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_tuple = false;
template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_content = false;
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_constructible = false;

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr bool is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> = true;
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr bool has_content<std::tuple<Ts...>> = sizeof...(Ts) > 0;
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr bool is_constructible <std::tuple<Ts...>> = std::conjunction_v<std::is_default_constructible<Ts>...>;

template <typename TupleType>
requires is_tuple<TupleType> && 
         has_content<TupleType> &&
         is_constructible<TupleType>

auto handle(std::string_view str)
{
    TupleType result;
    auto parse_one = [&](auto &arg)
    {
        auto [ field, rest ] = split(str, ',');
        arg = parse<decltype(arg)>(field);
        str = rest;
    };
    std::apply([&](auto &...args)
               { (parse_one(args), ...); },
               result);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    using LineData = std::tuple<std::string, double, int64_t>;
    std::string_view input_str = "first_cut,55.3,177";
    LineData result = handle<LineData>(input_str);

    std::cout << "Parsed values:" << '\n';
    std::cout << "String value: " << std::get<0>(result) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Double value: " << std::get<1>(result) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Int value: " << std::get<2>(result) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simplify the constraints

You defined three type trait checkers: `is_tuple`, `has_content` and `is_constructible`. Note that `has_content` is also only ever true if the type passed is a `std::tuple`, so `is_tuple` is redundant.

The names are also wrong: `has_content` doesn't say anything about it checking for tuples, and one would say that a non-empty `std::vector` also "has content". Maybe `is_nonempty_tuple` is better? One could also argue that while an empty tuple is a corner case, the code you've written will actually handle that correctly, so there is no need to prevent it.

`is_constructible` is also misnamed: again despite the name not saying it, it only is ever true for `std::tuple`s. But also note that "constructible" is not the same as "*default* constructible". So it should have been named `is_default_constructible_tuple`. However, there is no need to make such a check; `std::is_default_constructible_v<TupleType>` already checks that the whole tuple can be default constructed.

While you check that `TupleType` is a default-constructible, non-empty tuple, you didn't check whether the types stored in the tuple can actually be parsed. You could write a concept that checks whether you provide a default-constructible, non-empty, parsable `std::tuple`, but it would just duplicate the whole body of `handle()` inside a `requires` expression, which defeats the point.

I'd rather keep it simple:

```
template <typename TupleType>
requires is_tuple<TupleType> && 
         std::is_default_constructible_v<TupleType>
auto handle(std::string_view str) …
```

## Avoid needing the tuple type to be default-constructible

You can avoid default-constructing a `TupleType` by making use of the fact that you can return a value from `std::apply()`, and that you can already refer to a variable's name when constructing it:

```
auto handle(std::string_view str)
{
    auto parse_one = [&](auto &arg)
    {
        auto [ field, rest ] = split(str, ',');
        str = rest;
        return parse<decltype(arg)>(field);
    };
    TupleType result = std::apply([&](auto &...args)
               { return TupleType{parse_one(args)...}; },
               result);
    return result;
}
```

## Simplify returning values from `parse()`

I think your `parse()` is unnecessarily complex because you forgot to add `constexpr` to the second and third `if`-statement. I think you can completely avoid the temporary variable `res`:

```
template <typename T>
auto parse(std::string_view str)
{
    using T2 = std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T2, std::string>) { return str; }
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T2>) { return std::stod(std::string(str)); }
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T2>) { return std::stol(std::string(str)); }
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid type");
}
```

## Prefer using `std::from_chars()` to parse numeric values

Unfortunately, `std::stod()` and `std::stoi()` don't take `std::string_view`s as arguments, as you have discovered. I recommend you use [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) instead. It also doesn't take `std::string_view`s, but it takes pointers to the start and end of the string, which you can easily create from a `std::string_view`. It also avoids having to deal with integers and floating point values separately:

```
if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T2>) {
    if (T2 value; std::from_chars(str.begin(), str.end(), value) == std::errc{})
        return value;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Parse error");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your review, will take your input into considerations